# how to form a grid on a rectangle in matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, polygon

i have four points with that i made a polygon using matlab

```
x = [2271 -3645 -2267 3645];
y = [-3635 -2259 3639 2254];

figure;
plot([x x(1)],[y y(1)],'r-');
```

i got a polygon, i need to generate the grid above the rectangle with 50*50 interval

i made a try with zgrid function , but its not giving the result.

i need a 2D grid on that polygon, i need to take the grid points into a file.

please help me to solve this

thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear whether the points on the grid should be within the polygon or simply span the polygon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a grid with the `meshgrid` matlab's built-in function, and draw it with `mesh`  for example. The mesh coordinates are stored in `X` and `Y`.

Here the polygon you defined is plotted on the top of the grid. The following code

```
x = [2271 -3645 -2267 3645];  
y = [-3635 -2259 3639 2254];  

outside = 100;  
grid_val = 50;

figure('Color','w');  
[X,Y] = meshgrid(min(x)-outside:grid_val:max(x)+outside, min(y)-outside:grid_val:max(y)+outside);   
hold on;  
hm = mesh(X,Y,X*0);  
hp = plot([x x(1)],[y y(1)],'r-');  
set(hm,'EdgeColor','k')  
set(hp,'LineWidth',2)  
set(gca,'Visible','off');
```

gives the following grid (full and zoom)

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

To generate a point grid confined to the interior of your polygon you can do the following:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(min(x),max(x),round((max(x)-min(x))/50)),linspace(min(y),max(y),round((max(y)-min(y))/50)));
isin=inpolygon(X(:),Y(:),[x x(1)],[y y(1)]);
Xin = X(isin);
Yin = Y(isin);
```

Here `[Xin, Yin]` contains the coordinates of the grid vertices.

[image]

Comment: Can you supply your plotting code you used to generate the image or just some hints?